# Why does compiz window decorator crashes unity

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I used to run Unity 2D on my work machine. Now I am trying to use Unity. Everthing looks fine except for the missing window decoration. I have installed the compiz manager. Every time I activate the plugin "window decoration" Unity "crashes" the Unity bar along with the top panel .

unity --reset oder replace does nothing.

The command for the window manager is /usr/bin/compiz-decorator

Maybe I need to specify another window decorator?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, Unity and Compiz are not 100% compatible.  There are hacks out there to get some Compiz functionality working in Unity.  You just have to Google them.